# Flutter: make container occupy other container size within a Stack

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have a flutter app in which I have a stack and within a Container with some elements. I want to give some gesture detection and show an overlay layer when the user clicks on it. I have think of creating another container with the color and shape I want and then make it occupy the same space of the other container but above it.

The problem is that I can't figure out how to make the overlay container to have the same size than the main container.

This is what I have basically:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  bool _layerVisible = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    List<Widget> array = List();

    array.add(Stack(
      children: <Widget>[
        GestureDetector(
          onTapDown: (TapDownDetails details) {
            setState(() {
              _layerVisible = true;
            });
          },
          onTapUp: (TapUpDetails details) {
            setState(() {
              _layerVisible = false;
            });
          },
          child: Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
              color: Colors.yellow,
              child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Padding(
                    child: Text("Title text"),
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10),
                  ),
                  Text(
                      "Veeery long text. This is a dynamic value so we don't really know how long it's going to be...this means that the parent container is going to grow.")
                ],
              )),
        ),
        Visibility(
          visible: _layerVisible,
          child: Container(
            color: Colors.grey,
            child: Text(
                "This is the container that I want to fit exactly in the yellow container."),
          ),
        )
      ],
    ));

    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(widget.title),
        ),
        body: Container(
          width: 300,
          child: ListView(
            children: array,
          ),
        ));
  }
}
```

What I want is to make the last container within the stack to occupy the same space of the other container, this way I can create an overlay layer when I click on it.

I try using Expanded, using Positioned.fill, but none of this solution works for me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using an [`IntrinsicHeight`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/IntrinsicHeight-class.html) above your `Stack`. It'll give an explicit size based off the largest widget in the stack to the `Stack` itself. Then, make sure you add a `fit: StackFit.passthrough,` on the `Stack`. That'll pass down the sizing information from `IntrinsicHeight` to all of it's children.